# Secure Communication between ASP Pages and Cocoa/ObjC

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, security, asp-classic

This is an odd one. I developed a simple iPhone application for management at my company to check real time sales statistics. The first hurdle was figuring out how to get the app to communicate with our old MSSQL 2005 server. After some research it seemed like the fastest way to do it was to create a basic ASP page that would spit out query results with response.write() calls. This works pretty well actually- but the ASP page that returns the results is open to the entire world. The only 'security' mechanism I've got on it isn't really one at all- changing the HTTP port on the server side.

So my question is- what are best practices for this? What would work between ASP and Objective-C? I've read up on some basic challenge-response, encryption, and the like, but it seems like overkill for a simple string of generally unintelligible sales numbers. As the app develops into something more complex however, I'd like this problem solved before the asp starts sending back more sensitive data.

Here is my connection to server code, if it helps. The constant is just there so I can append POST data to it to get to different stats based on what I want from the app. The logic for this is elsewhere and not really important.

```
NSString * const appDataUrl = @"http://{the url for the asp page}";

//Don't ask me how this works. Google FTW...
-(NSString *) pullData:(NSString *) url {
    NSError * error = nil;
    NSURLResponse * response = nil;
    NSData * downloadedData = 
        [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:
         [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
          [NSURL URLWithString:url]] returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    NSString *strData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:downloadedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    return strData;
}
```

Thanks guys.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Feel free to read [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/FAQ) and stay awhile. Also, don't hesitate to pick a username and gravatar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use HTTP Authentication (Digest for example) in which you would add a username and password to each request. I don't know if Objective-C has the necessary library to generate the relevant digest token, but if it doesn't you can use one of the HTTP libraries available which I'm sure can handle that.

You can then add the authentication required inside IIS so that only people who know the username and password can access that URL.

Another way of doing that would be to add a special header to the HTTP request in Objective-C, something like X-Auth with a special random value (it can be a predefined GUID).

The request will be sent with that special header and you can check its existence and its value in ASP.

I would also suggest adding SSL so you can access this request via HTTPS so that no one can sniff the data out.

Comment: Excellent, that sounds like the best solution for now. So basically I can do something like setting that constant to @"http://myurl.com?auth=blahblahblahsomethingcrazy and check it in my asp code, then use SSL to hide that information stream. I need to research SSL more but this is a good first step.

Comment: The best way to make sure nothing is saved is perform an HTTP POST from your objective-c code with the "auth" parameter. Or, pass that parameter is an HTTP HEADER (not a URL query parameter).

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the communications with SSL.

Based on your use case, you want only your app (running on the iPhone) to be able to access your webservice. To do this, configure mutually-authenticated SSL between your app and the endpoint on your webserver where the ASP service runs. If you only have your app communicating with your server, you don't need CA-issued SSL certificates but can use self-signed ones. Deploy a self-signed identity certificate on your server and deploy a self-signed client identity certificate within your app, as a resource. Configure your server to require client certificates and only allow the one you issued and your app is using; this will cause your server to only accept requests from your client app. Configure your client to only trust the server certificate deployed on your server (so it can only talk to your server to get this data) and to present the client certificate upon connection (so it can authenticate itself to the server). Then, only your app can call into your server, the client can only get the data from your valid source, and the entire transaction is encrypted and authenticated.

Comment: +1 for not embedding username/password or making people enter them on an iDevice.